# In the Codex Alera books, what names are given to Water and Wood Knights?

Tags: jim-butcher, codex-alera

In the Codex Alera books, the Knights are grouped by element, each with a special name, like Knights Aeris for the knights that use wind.

- Earth: Terra
- Fire: Ignus
- Wind: Aris
- Water:
- Metal: Ferris
- Wood:

Waht are the names given to Water and Wood?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Water : Knights Aqua
- Wood : Knights Flora

Note: In Chapter 47, Furies of Calderon, the term used for knight controlling wood furies is Knights Fauna. Everywhere else the term is Knights Flora.

Comment: You'd think Knights Flora would make more sense....

Comment: @Beofett, actually i think you might be right.  i'll have to do some digging.

Comment: The more I think of it, the more I believe Flora was the term used in the books.

Comment: @Beofett,@DForck42: I'm pretty sure the source I cited used Fauna, but perhaps that was a typo in the book. Will try to check in other places. Alternatively, maybe the author thought Knights Flora was too flowery a name for knights.

Comment: According to Amazon's "search inside" (http://www.amazon.com/Furies-Calderon-Codex-Alera-Book/dp/044101268X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1312630246&sr=8-1) it is indeed Fauna.

Comment: @Tony interesting. Apparently either the terms are interchangeable, or one of the terms is errata. Amazon "search inside" for Captain's Fury, Cursor's Fury, and Academ's Fury each show that Knight Flora was used repeatedly, but never Fauna. It seems Fauna is used only in the first book, and only once.

Answer (score 4):

- Water: Knights Aqua
- Wood: Knights Flora

The first book in the series appears to mention Knights Fauna, but this appears to be a mistake.  Every other reference in the series mentions Knights Flora.